# Form data not visible in new page - PHP + Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page containing a set of hyperlinks. Clicking on any of the hyperlinks should take the user to a new page with the url sent as `POST` data.

What I am able to do:
1. Open the new page.

What issues I am facing:
1. In the new page, I am trying to access the url that was sent across as data. The url is not visible. Where am I going wrong?

The code I have so far:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title></title>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        function takeMeHome(obj) {
                                var URL = obj.getAttribute("href");
                                //alert("Url = " + URL + " with id = " + obj.id);
                                console.log("URL = " + URL);
                                 $.ajax({
                                         type: 'POST',
                                         url: './bbCloud.php',
                                         data: {'tgt_url': URL},
                                         success:function(data) {
                                                 console.log("Function invoked. It seems posting data was a success");
                                                 window.location = URL;
                                                 //alert('This was sent back: ' + data);
                                         }
                                });
                                return false;
                        }
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <p>
                        Choose one of the links below to access content:</p>
                <p><a href="./bbCloud.php" id="link1" onclick="takeMeHome(this); return false;">1. Email Etiquette</a></p>
        </body>
</html>
```

bbCloud.php:

```
<?php
//the function below displays data from bbMainPage javascript.
function getDataFromLibrary() {

    $tgt_url = $_POST["tgt_url"];
    echo "Data received = " . $tgt_url . "<br/>";
    return $tgt_url;
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<style>
.hlight{background-color:#ffcc00;}
textarea {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myDomain/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//mention all global variables here.
console.log("this is the start of javascript");
//get all data from the previous script.
var tgtURL = "<?php getDataFromLibrary(); ?>";
console.log("URl obtained = " + tgtURL);
    </script>

<body>
<div>
<audio id="playText" src="" controls></audio>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because if you redirect to a URL it doesn't carry over the previously made `POST`. You'd be better off using a `GET`

Comment: @MrHunter: No, GET does not work either.

Comment: After the `POST` request is made you can't just redirect to it hoping that the variables are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try dynamically creating and submiting a form instead of trying to ajax it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function takeMeHome(obj) {
                    var URL = obj.getAttribute("href");
                    $('<form>', {
                        "html": '<input type="text" name="tgt_url" value="' + URL + '" />',
                        "action": URL
                    }).appendTo(document.body).submit();
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is trying to `ajax` it the problem? Why?

Comment: i believe so. You are performing an ajax post with a callback method. Once you receive the callback method, the post has already completed and the POST data is gone by the time you call window.location

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if I recall correctly, what is happening is that your `$.ajax` does indeed send the POST data to your php file. The problem is, that it sends the post data, the php file is executed, and a response is sent back, but its sent back to the `$.ajax` call itself. You THEN redirect to the php file (and thus run it again), but without the post data coming along. Also, something along the lines of `$.('a').click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }` might be a good idea. I'll try and make a better answer for you when I get home (currently on my phone, shouldn't be long).